# none and other options not displaying on dropdown options in surveyjs with react

Tags: reactjs, survey, surveyjs

I checked allow the other option and allow the none option boxes creating drop down survey on surveyjs. Both of options display on surveyjs.io ui but not on react js app. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here are the drop down choices:[image: img]

I checked the following checkboxes

[image: img] [image: img]

json editor:[image: img]

preview on surveyjs.io:
[image: img]

code:

```
import 'survey-core/modern.min.css';
import { StylesManager, Model } from 'survey-core';
import { Survey } from 'survey-react-ui';

StylesManager.applyTheme("modern");

export function App() {

   const json = {
        surveyId: 'fff11111',
        resultId: 'aaaaa11111',
        postId:'11111bbbb',
      };
  
   const survey = new Model(json);
   return (<Survey model={survey} />)

}
```

result on local:

[image: img]

versions of surveyjs libraries i am using: 1.9.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is upgrading your survey runner libraries. You use outdated version of SurveyJS libraries.